# Android Manifest Instrumentation

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-testing

I have a `android test project` setup to test my `android project`. In the `android test project`'s manifest, I have an entry for `instrumentation`. It looks like:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.company.android" />
```

I'm curious what the point of this entry is, and particuarly what the purpose of `android:targetPackage="com.company.android"` is for. I ask, because I refactored the old project and put classes into different packages, so I'm curious on what I need to update this value to... is it suppose to point the the package where the class that extends `android.app.Application` is at?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It tells the build system where to access the actual project you are going to test.

This is necessary because you need access to all your Activities and classes without having extra copies around.

Info about it is scattered around in: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

Comment: which package should it be pointing to? Where the activities are, or where the application is? p.s. love the handle.

Comment: Often where the activities are and where the app is are the same. The're the same in my apps that I have test apps for. I suppose it wants to know the app package because at the very least, it needs to access the app before looking for activities.

Comment: compiling... we'll see if that is the case :)

Comment: Sweet! Got me past where I was... still have issues but that gave me what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

[InstrumentationTestRunner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html) is something you use to write Android unit tests.

From the documentation:

```
Typical Usage

Write TestCases that perform unit, functional, or performance tests against the classes in your package. 
Typically these are subclassed from:

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
ActivityUnitTestCase
AndroidTestCase
ApplicationTestCase
InstrumentationTestCase
ProviderTestCase
ServiceTestCase
SingleLaunchActivityTestCase

In an appropriate AndroidManifest.xml, define the this instrumentation with the appropriate android:targetPackage set.
Run the instrumentation using "adb shell am instrument -w", with no optional arguments, to run all tests (except performance tests).
Run the instrumentation using "adb shell am instrument -w", with the argument '-e func true' to run all functional tests. These are tests that derive from InstrumentationTestCase.
Run the instrumentation using "adb shell am instrument -w", with the argument '-e unit true' to run all unit tests. These are tests that do notderive from InstrumentationTestCase (and are not performance tests).
Run the instrumentation using "adb shell am instrument -w", with the argument '-e class' set to run an individual TestCase.
```